# How to customize TextBlock using OnRender

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I can't get this...I am beginning to think it can't be done.

I would like to create a custom textblock control that allows measuring of the contained text. I can *not* do the below since OnRender() is sealed. However, if I use *new*, my new "OnRender()" is never called. So how can it be done? Is there a better way? (The CustomTextBlock is used within an ItemsControl in an MVVM framework. I do not want to create any additional dependency properties).

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Useage in XAML:

```
 <i:CustomTextBlock Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="tbc"
               Text="{Binding Text}" 
               FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" 
               FontStyle="Italic" 
               Foreground="{Binding Color}" 
               FontFamily="Segoe Script" />
```

Control definition:

```
 public class CustomTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public CustomTextBlock() : base()
    {
    }

 // THIS FAILS...BUT "NEW" IS NEVER CALLED???
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(this.FontFamily,
            this.FontStyle,
            this.FontWeight,
            this.FontStretch); 

        FormattedText formmatedText = new FormattedText(
            this.Text,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
            this.FlowDirection,
            typeface,
            this.FontSize,
            this.Foreground);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735387/wpf-textblock-cannot-override-onrender

Comment: @asb Thanks. I missed that. However, I did not see an answer there???

Comment: Why not derive from FrameworkElement, define the required properties (`Text`, `Font*` and `Foreground`, by `DependencyProperty.AddOwner`) and override `OnRender`?

Comment: @Clemens Yep. That's the other approach. I was hoping to use as much of the standard controls as possible thinking they execute faster(??). Also learning if anybody knows how to use OnRender() with a textblock. Interesting that prewired events in a UserControl assume the code-behind as their datacontext.

Comment: @Clemens Just reviewed DependencyProperty.AddOwner. That will do it. WPF has such a steep learning curve. Thanks.

Comment: You would do it with all needed TextBlock properties like `public static readonly FontSizeProperty = TextBlock.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomTextBlock));` and then also write the CLR property wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out anyway around OnRender, but this worked to solve my issue. This is a possible solution, although not really an answer.

In the code-behind of the UserControl, where the XAML defines the TextBlock with x:Name="tbc".

Hope this helps somebody.

```
   public partial class InkStringView : UserControl
{
    public InkStringView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        tbc.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(InkStringView_Loaded);
    }

    void InkStringView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;

        Typeface typeface = new Typeface(
          tb.FontFamily,
          tb.FontStyle,
          tb.FontWeight,
          tb.FontStretch);

       FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
            tb.Text,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
            tb.FlowDirection,
            typeface,
            tb.FontSize,
            tb.Foreground);

        StringViewModel svm = tb.DataContext as StringViewModel;
        svm.Bounds = formattedText.GetBoundingRect();
        svm.MidlineY1 = svm.MidlineY2 =  svm.Bounds.Top + 0.45 * (formattedText.Baseline - svm.Bounds.Top);


        double width = tb.ActualWidth;
        double height = tb.ActualHeight;

        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
        while (!(parent is Window))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }


        GeneralTransform gt = tb.TransformToAncestor(parent as UIElement);
        Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        double controlTop = offset.Y;
        double controlLeft = offset.X;
    }       
}
```